# Sort and parse multi level of JSON with recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, recursion

It's my first time when I am trying to use recursion in javascript and I need some help to understand it.

I have this JSON with multi levels of "subcategories"

```
    var STORE_CATEGORIES = [{
        "Id":"1",
        "Name":"One Parent",
        "Sort":"0",
        "Subcategories":[
            "Id":"1",
            "Name":"One Subcategory",
            "Sort":"0",
            "Subcategories":[{
                "Id":"1",
                "Name":"One SubSubcategory",
                "Sort":"0",
                "Subcategories":[{
                     .....
                }]
            }]
        ]},
        "Id":"2",
        "Name":"Two Parent",
        "Sort":"1",
        ....
    ]}
```

and this is my script until now:

```
function sortJSON(json, output, prop, asc){
    json = json.sort(function(a, b){
        if(asc){
            return (a[prop] > b[prop]) ? 1 : ((a[prop] < b[prop]) ? -1 : 0);
        } else {
            return (b[prop] > a[prop]) ? 1 : ((b[prop] < a[prop]) ? -1 : 0);
        }
    });
    showJsonResults(json, output);
}
function showJsonResults(json, output){
    var parent = output;
    var list = $('<ul />').appendTo(parent);
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var result = json[i];
        html += '<li data-sort="'+result.Sort+'" data-id="'+result.Id+'"';
        if(result.Visible == false){
            html += ' class="hide"';
        }
        html += '><a href="'+result.URL+'">'+result.Name+'</a>';
        if(result.Subcategories){
            html += '<ul>';
            for (key in result.Subcategories) {
                var sub = result.Subcategories[key];
                html += '<li data-sort="'+sub.Sort+'" data-id="'+sub.Id+'"';
                if(sub.Visible == false){
                    html += ' class="hide"';
                }
                html += '><a href="'+sub.URL+'">'+sub.Name+'</a>';
                html += '</li>';
            }
            html += '</ul>';
        }
        html += '</li>';
    }
    list.append(html);
}
```

Function to call:

```
sortJSON(STORE_CATEGORIES, $('.categories div'), 'Sort', true);
```

Now I am getting only categories + subcategories, but there are more subcategories of subcategories.

How can I use recursion here?
Thanks.

Comment: what's your goal?

Comment: need to use recursion to get all subcategories, not only first categories..need to display subcategories of subcategories too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter your functions slightly:

```
    function sortJSON(json, output, prop, asc){
        json = json.sort(function(a, b){
            if(asc){
                return (a[prop] > b[prop]) ? 1 : ((a[prop] < b[prop]) ? -1 : 0);
            } else {
                return (b[prop] > a[prop]) ? 1 : ((b[prop] < a[prop]) ? -1 : 0);
            }
        });
        var parent = output;
        var list = $('<ul />').appendTo(parent);
        var html = showJsonResults(json);
        list.append(html);
    }
function showJsonResults(json) {
   var html = '';
   $.each(json, function(i, result) {
     html += '<li data-sort="' + result.Sort + '" data-id="' + result.Id + '"';
     if (result.Visible == false) {
       html += ' class="hide"';
     }
     html += '><a href="' + result.URL + '">' + result.Name + '</a>';
     if (result.Subcategories.length) { //if you have subcategories call the function again
       console.log(result.Subcategories[0].Name);
       html += '<ul>' + showJsonResults(result.Subcategories) + '</ul>';
     }

     html += '</li>';
   });
   return html
 }
}
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/neLbgp4r/1/

Comment: is not working, I think that entire function need to be somehow rewritten

Comment: no other subcategories.. with or without that `if` is the same result

Comment: [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/templatetuners/neLbgp4r/2/) can you please take a look here? still not getting 3rd level of categories

Comment: give me a 3th lvl item

Comment: aaa my fault, sorry - json is broken, thank you for your answer!